# After git, folders and files gone

Tags: git

I had a directory such that

```
$ ls
$ README.md testA.c testB.c a_large_folder another_folder
```

my most recent add->commit->push consisted of

```
$ README.md testA.c
```

Normally, my lazy self is used to doing `git add .` but this time I simply wanted to add `a_large_folder`.

When I did,

```
$ git add a_large_folder
```

I was prompted back `fatal: pathspec 'a_large_folder' did not match any files`. So of course I googled "git add folders" with the first SO answer saying to `git add <folder>/*`.

Well, I stupidly wrote `git add a_large_folder\` (notice the wrong slash). This resulted in,

```
 >
```

as if it executed an interpeter. I, again being stupid, wrote `:q` because I've been in vim all day so I wasn't thinking about whether that would actually quit or not.

Now, all of my files after my most recent commit are gone; aka only `READ.md testA.c` are left in my directory. The other stuff appears as if it's been `rm -rf`

Not a big deal but curious why this deleted my files/folders in this directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: you did not have the directory `a_large_folder` inside when running `git add`.

This is the only reason for `git add a_large_folder` to report:

> pathspec 'a_large_folder' did not match any files

The syntax is correct and works for either for specific files as well as for a containing directory. See [add.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/add.c).

---

If you confirmed your second command which you split over several lines, it also failed with:

> fatal: pathspec 'a_large_folder:q' did not match any files